Multiple expandable SliverAppBar overlap in CustomScrollView
When I use multiple expandable SliverAppBars in CustomScrollView, the second SliverAppBar and the subsequent Sliver will overlap before compression.
CustomScrollView(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(
          pinned: true,
          stretch: true,
          expandedHeight: 200,
          collapsedHeight: 100,
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
        ),
        SliverList.list(
            children: List.generate(
                10,
                (index) => Text(
                      index.toString(),
                    ))),
        SliverAppBar(
          pinned: true,
          expandedHeight: 200,
          collapsedHeight: 100,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5),
        ),
        SliverList.list(
            children: List.generate(
                40,
                (index) =>
                    Text(index.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20))))
      ],
    )


I've tried implementing this using a NestedScrollView with a SliverOverlapAbsorber/Injector, but this leads to another problem.
Unsetting the expandedHeight property of the SliverAppBar avoids this problem, but I need to use the expanded functionality of the SliverAppBar.
Thank you very much for your attention！
